# Regex replace tag to tag in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone let me know the regex pattern for the following case,

Input: variable : parseddata

```
<root>
<A></A>
<location>
<city>mycity</city>
<city1>mycity1</city1>
<state>mystate</state>
</location>
<B></B>
<root>
```

Replacement text: updatedLocation

```
<updatedlocation>
<updatedcity>mycity</updatedcity>
<updatedstate>mystate</updatedstate>
</updatedlocation>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
<A></A>
<updatedlocation>
<updatedcity>mycity</updatedcity>
<updatedstate>mystate</updatedstate>
</updatedlocation>
<B></B>
<root>
```

regexLocationPattern = ??;
In C#, how to write regex pattern for this,

```
patchedData = Regex.Replace(parseddata, regexLocationPattern, updatedLocation);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Input, Output, Expected output ? What have you tried ?

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/WL7e6YOWNM

Your replacement string should look like: "<updatedlocation>\n<updatedcity>$1</updatedcity>\n<updatedstate>$3</updatedstate>\n</updatedlocation>"

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex like this:

```
<location>[^\0]*?<\/location>
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/mQ2qV0/1)

Comment: @JavierBuzzi. He want to replace `<location>` content by `<updatedlocation>`. Am I wrong?

Comment: "WITH" the data inside. I did this: rubular.com/r/WL7e6YOWNM but i don't know enough c# to give OP a full answer. but see how the values are extracted?

Comment: He already have a var named updatedLocation with the _updated location_

Comment: The way i read that was he doesnt, thats what OP wants to replace it WITH. Not what OP has, OPs first string block is what he has, the last string block is what OP wants. See "input"

Comment: I see your point.. let's wait for the feedback.. If I am wrong, I will delete my answer

Comment: Added my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var input = @"<root>\n<A></A>\n<location>\n<city>mycity</city>\n<city1>mycity1</city1>\n<state>mystate</state>\n</location>\n<B></B>\n<root>";
var replacement = @"<updatedlocation>\n<updatedcity>${city}</updatedcity>\n<updatedstate>${state}</updatedstate>\n</updatedlocation>";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?sn)<location>(\r?\n)*((<city>(?<city>.*?)</city>)|(<city1>(?<city1>.*?)</city1>)|(<state>(?<state>.*?)</state>)|\r?\n)+</location>");

var result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
```

The regex to search is:

```
(?s)<location>(\r?\n)((<city>(?<city>.*?)</city>)|(<city1>(?<city1>.*?)</city1>)|(<state>(?<state>.*?)</state>)|\r?\n)+</location>
```

The replacement is:

```
<updatedlocation>
<updatedcity>${city}</updatedcity>
<updatedstate>${state}</updatedstate>
</updatedlocation>
```

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/Cw7feM)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this to replace whatever the data inside the location tag to be replace with the updatedLocation data.

```
var regexLocationPattern = @"<location.*</location>";

patchedData = Regex.Replace(parseddata, regexLocationPattern, updatedLocation);
```

The output i got,

```
   <root>
    <A></A>
    <updatedlocation>
    <updatedcity>mycity</updatedcity>
    <updatedstate>mystate</updatedstate>
    </updatedlocation>
    <B></B>
    <root>
```

Please let know if there is any problem with this?

(ignore the new line cases)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are not forced to use a RegEx, cause RegEx and XML doesn't work together very well. I would prefer an XML parser, which makes the code a little bit longer, but far more readable and maintainable:

```
var parsedData = Properties.Resources.Content;
var document = XDocument.Parse(parsedData);
var root = (XElement)document.FirstNode;

var location = root.Element("location");
location.Name = "updatedLocation";

location.Element("city1").Remove();

var city = location.Element("city");
city.Name = "updatedCity";

var state = location.Element("state");
state.Name = "updatedState";

var result = document.ToString();
```

Within the code some nullity checks are missing, but you should get the idea on how to manipulate the xml stuff.

And one additional note:
Within your given example data is an error. The last node `root` is missing the slash, which makes it an illegal xml document. Hopefully this is just a typo from your site and not an error within the received data.